# MyStateObject was disposed when I navigated back from Screen2 to Screen1

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I will post my projects minimum classes here that you can reproduce the faulty behavior.

The listing of the classes here goes mostly from the top of the flutter widget hierarchy down the rest...

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:TestIt/widgets/applicationpage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  final ApplicationPage applicationPage =
      ApplicationPage(title: 'Flutter Demo');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          // This is the theme of your application.
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: applicationPage);
  }
}
```

**applicationpage.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'body.dart';

class ApplicationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ApplicationPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _ApplicationPageState createState() => _ApplicationPageState();
}

class _ApplicationPageState extends State<ApplicationPage> {
  final Body body = new Body();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: body);
  }
}
```

**body.dart**

```
import 'package:TestIt/viewmodels/excercise.dart';
import 'package:TestIt/viewmodels/workout.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'Excercises/ExcerciseListWidget.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var workouts = new List<Workout>();
    var pullDay = new Workout("Pull day", new List<Excercise>());
    workouts.add(pullDay);
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: DefaultTabController(
            // Added
            length: workouts.length, // Added
            initialIndex: 0, //Added
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: PreferredSize(
                  // todo: add AppBar widget here again
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
                  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                    TabBar(
                      indicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                      isScrollable: true,
                      tabs: getTabs(workouts),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                        height: 30,
                        width: 30,
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                            heroTag: null,
                            child: Icon(Icons.add),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                            elevation: 5.0,
                            onPressed: () => print("add workout"))),
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                        height: 30,
                        width: 30,
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                            heroTag: null,
                            child: Icon(Icons.remove),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                            elevation: 5.0,
                            onPressed: () => print("add workout"))),
                  ])),
              body: TabBarView(
                children: getTabViews(workouts),
              ),
            )));
  }

  List<ExcerciseListWidget> getTabViews(List<Workout> workouts) {
    var tabViews = new List<ExcerciseListWidget>();
    for (var i = 0; i < workouts.length; i++) {
      tabViews.add(ExcerciseListWidget(workouts[i].excercises));
    }
    return tabViews;
  }

  List<Tab> getTabs(List<Workout> workouts) {
    Color textColor = Colors.blueAccent;
    return workouts
        .map((w) => new Tab(
              child: Text(w.name, style: TextStyle(color: textColor)),
            ))
        .toList();
  }
}
```

**ExcerciseListWidget.dart**

```
import 'package:TestIt/viewmodels/excercise.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'ExcerciseWidget.dart';

class ExcerciseListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ExcerciseListWidget(this.excercises);
  final List<Excercise> excercises;

  @override
  _ExcerciseListWidgetState createState() => _ExcerciseListWidgetState();
}

class _ExcerciseListWidgetState extends State<ExcerciseListWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              widget.excercises.insert(
                  0,
                  new Excercise(widget.excercises.length + 1, "test",
                      widget.excercises.length * 10));
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 5.0,
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
            child: ReorderableListView(
                onReorder: (index1, index2) => {
                      print("onReorder"),
                    },
                children: widget.excercises
                    .map((excercise) => ExcerciseWidget(
                        key: ValueKey(excercise.id), excercise: excercise))
                    .toList())));
  }
}
```

**ExcerciseWidget.dart**

```
import 'package:TestIt/viewmodels/excercise.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'ExcerciseDetailsWidget.dart';

class ExcerciseWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ExcerciseWidget({this.key, this.excercise}) : super(key: key);
  final Excercise excercise;
  final Key key;

  @override
  _ExcerciseWidgetState createState() => _ExcerciseWidgetState();
}

class _ExcerciseWidgetState extends State<ExcerciseWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0, bottom: 3.0),
        // TODo: with this ink box decoration the scrolling of the excercises goes under the tabbar... but with the ink I have a ripple effect NOT under
        // the element...
        child: Ink(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(5.0)),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.orange),
              color: Colors.green),
          child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => {navigateToEditScreen(context)},
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      color: Colors.red, child: Text(widget.excercise.name)),
                ],
              )),
        ));
  }

  navigateToEditScreen(BuildContext context) async {
    final Excercise result = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                ExcerciseDetailsWidget(excercise: widget.excercise)));

    setState(() {
      widget.excercise.name = result.name;
    });
  }
}
```

**ExcerciseDetailsWidget.dart**

```
import 'package:TestIt/viewmodels/excercise.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExcerciseDetailsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Excercise excercise;
  ExcerciseDetailsWidget({Key key, @required this.excercise}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExcerciseDetailsWidgetState createState() => _ExcerciseDetailsWidgetState();
}

class _ExcerciseDetailsWidgetState extends State<ExcerciseDetailsWidget> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.excercise.name),
        ),
        body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 2, top: 2),
            child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  new RaisedButton(
                      elevation: 2,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Text('Save'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          widget.excercise.name = "new name";
                        });
                        Navigator.pop(context, widget.excercise);
                      }),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      //hintText: 'excercise name',
                      labelText: 'Excercise name',
                    ),
                    initialValue: widget.excercise.name,
                  ),
                ]))));
  }
}
```

**workout.dart**

```
 import 'excercise.dart';

    class Workout{
        Workout(this.name, this.excercises);
        String name;
        List<Excercise> excercises;
    }
```

**excercise.dart**

```
class Excercise {
  int id;

  Excercise(this.id,this.name,  this.restBetweenSetsInSeconds);
  String name;
  int restBetweenSetsInSeconds;
}
```

**How to reproduce the faulty behavior to get the exception:**

1. Click on the bottom-right floating action button to create an excercise test stub which is added to the only existing workout.
2. Click the newly added excercise
3. The ExcerciseDetailsWidget is loaded
4. Click Save in the ExcerciseDetailsWidget
5. Navigation goes back to the Initial screen and the Exception hits you in the face bam!

**Exception**

FlutterError (setState() called after dispose(): **_ExcerciseWidgetState**#bccdb(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().)

**Question**

Why is the formerly added and clicked ExcerciseWidget`s State disposed when I returned from the ExcerciseDetailsWidget ?

Check for is mounted and then call setState is no solution because in any case the excercise should NOT be disposed because I have to update it with the new excercise name.

If you know a flutter online site where I can put the project I will do so please let me know!

I am a flutter beginner maybe I do something completely wrong bear that in mind :-)

**UPDATE**

What I have done to workaround the problem is:

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                ExcerciseDetailsWidget(excercise: widget.excercise)));
```

do not await the result of the Navigator.

Instead I do this in the Screen2:

```
onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
```

// WHY can I set here the new text WITHOUT setState but when I navigated back the new excercise name is reflected in the list of excercises. Actually that should not be the case right? That confuses me totally.

```
                            widget.excercise.name =
                                excerciseNameTextController.value.text;

                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        }
                      },
```

but this is really just a workaround that works in this special **EDIT** use case.

When I have an **ADD** use case I need to return something to add it to the list of excercises...

Could it be that the problem is that I await the result inside the excercise?
I guess I will try to await the result excercise on the context/level of the ExercerciseListWidget not inside the ExcerciseWidget.

**UPDATE 2**

Reading more about the navigator it seems or could be that when I am navigating back to the former route which is my initial/root that all the knowledge about the clicked excercise is gone? Do I need therefore kind of nested routing? like "/workouts/id/excercises/id" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the downvotes, this is a legitimate question. After poking around a little bit, the reason seems to be the `ReorderableListView`. For some reason, even if you are providing keys to each child of the list, when the `ReorderableListView` is rebuilt, all of its children are disposed and reinitialized. Because of this, when you navigate back from `ExcerciseDetailsWidget`, you are calling `setState` within a state that has been disposed - this is why you are getting that specific exception.

Frankly, your current code makes it very difficult to figure out whether it's something you've done wrong or a bug related to `ReorderableListView`. The only thing that can be said for sure is that replacing the `ReorderableListView` with a regular `ListView` will fix it.

I highly recommend cleaning up your code first - my IDE lit up like a Christmas tree when I copied your code in. Get rid of the `new` keyword. Use `const` constructors. Fix the `Excercise` typo that repeats itself 60 times in 250 rows of code.

And most importantly, given that you are mutating and displaying a data object across multiple stateful widgets, start using Provider for state management.

Comment: I really questioned all my knowledge I gained the last 2 weeks starting with flutter just of this bug... I replaced the ReorderableListView which is really missing much ListView functionality with a ListView and the exception is gone.

Comment: I asked for a place where to put all that code runnable but you did not say ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your const/new tips. Ah the excercise is great "DE-english" ;-)

Comment: It is correct that the EXERCISE and its children... -which I removed here - is used in a readonly view aka ExcerciseListWidget and inside the ExcerciseDetailsWidget.Why should I start using provider if it works without? I first want to learn flutter then upgrade if its really needed. Thanks though for the hint.

Comment: Quick question ;-) Do you have any idea why in Screen1 the exercise name is still updated in the UI although I removed every setState call? I do not understand that.

Comment: About the quick question: THIS is really really bad. I realized that the hot reload does sometimes not correct reflect the current saved changes in the code. That happened before too. Now when I do an explicit RESTART of the debugging the UI exercise name update NEEDS a setState pfffffffffffffffffffffffhhhhh....

Comment: Provider is not mandatory - but it makes your life easier as the app gets more complex, and has other benefits that you will learn over time. But yes it's probably better to get a good understanding of how Flutter works before using it. The reason the name updates even without calling `setState` is that you have already set the new value of `name` of the Exercise object on Screen 2, so when you go back to Screen 1, Flutter will rebuild it in order to display it, and the new name is shown. It's because you are mutating the SAME object on Screen 2 that you passed from Screen 1. It's standard OOP

Comment: Hot Reload will rebuild the entire widget hierarchy, while maintaining the state. The reason all your data is erased is that you are not storing it in the state. You have this code: `var workouts = new List<Workout>();` within the `build` function of `Body`. Every time the `Body` widget needs to rebuild, such as Hot Reload, `workouts` is reinitialized. Hot Restart will clear the state as well - as if you have closed the app and opened it again.

Comment: About your "mutating the same object" as I said before it needed setState, there was just a hot reload problem having old state it seemed. Normally prop changes should not be reflected in the UI without any setState according to flutter docs. See here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html   " If you just change the state directly without calling setState, the framework might not schedule a build and the user interface for this subtree might not be updated to reflect the new state."

Comment: The documentation is entirely correct - if you simply change the data, the UI will not reflect it without a rebuild. This is usually done by calling `setState`, but in your case the data is changed just before navigating from Screen 2 back to Screen 1, which also triggers a rebuild without you having to call `setState`. In fact, because you are calling `setState`, the widget will rebuild twice within a single frame. While this might not result in frames being skipped (depending on the complexity of the UI and the processing power of the device), it is not optimal.

Comment: I am just testing provider... so I can not test my old working code atm. But are you sure about this: "...data is changed just before navigating from Screen 2 back to Screen 1..." What triggers a rebuild here? That I navigate from screen 2 back to screen 1 ? If yes can that be generally  formulated like using Navigation.Pop() will always trigger a rebuild of the UI to which the user is returned?

Comment: crazy... I just do this in a ExerciseModelExtendsChangeNotifier: set name(String name) {
    excercise.name = name;
    //notifyListeners();
  } When I return to Screen1 then the existing exercise name is updated witout any setState/notifyListeners() AND the widget displaying the workouts/exercises is NOT rebuilt because I have a breakpoint there... Its OOP yes but it should not reflect in the UI ??? I dont get it! I need to play more with the flutttttttterrrrr

Comment: OK it is REBUILT. To be clear the widget triggering the Navigator.push(...) is rebuilt which owns the list of excercises. Good that put the AddExercise button there ;-) That means for screen overlapping changes I do not need setState/notifylisteners()

Comment: "If yes can that be generally formulated like using Navigation.Pop() will always trigger a rebuild of the UI to which the user is returned?" - No. While this is true for navigating between full screen pages, if you simply display a dialog/popup, and then dismiss it using `Navigator.pop()`, nothing else is rebuilt because the dialog was just stacked on top of a page that was already built and displayed behind the dialog. If you want a 'general formula', think of it this way - if you want to display any widget that's not already **on the screen**, it needs to be built first.

Comment: Yeah my rebuilt page is a full screen page! thanks for your tips. I just enjoy provider but have many questions ;-)